# Create gem server for chef required gems for linux and windows gems

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra

I have created some internal recipes that require gems, and because these systems do not have Internet access, I would like to create a repository server, such as spacewalk for redhat/centos, but for gems that I use on my chef enabled hosts.

I have checked a few posts mentioning 'gem server' as a solution, but what I didn't find out is if 'gem server' does what I want AND is platform and OS independent (i686, x86_64 etc.).

So, I guess my question in a few words is: Could I have a single, internal, gem server for all of my OSes and platforms and use 'gem install chef' on a client no matter what the OS or platform is?

Comment: Hi I am building a gem server on redhat. Can you please guide me through the installation of the gem server.

Comment: I am building a gem server. Because of the security limitations i am not supposed to use rubygems.org and i am planning to download the gems and keep the gems in redhat gemserver and install them when need in my puppet master and agents.

Answer (score 0):

All you need a static file server. It would also be platform independent, as the .gemspec for any gem needs to specify any platform and Ruby requirements.

Check out http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18